# Smooth model created in Blender has surface imperfections in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, game-physics, blender

So, this might be a SceneKit/iOS problem -- but it might instead be a Blender problem. This question presupposes the former.

Let's say I open a fresh project in Blender (nothing fancy) and export the default cube it creates as a `dae` file. I then import that `dae` file into my Xcode SceneKit project.

This particular SceneKit project consists of a scene in which a small ball rolls around on the top surface of a cube.

**The problem:** If I use SceneKit's built-in `SCNBox` shape for the cube (with a static, `convexHull` physics body), the ball rolls smoothly, as desired. *But if I use the model exported from Blender, the ball bounces along the cube's surface as though it were covered in small, invisible bumps.*

**What I've tried:**

1. I tried increasing the ball's mass from 2.0 to 100.0 just to see if that would affect the outcome.
2. I tried applying some smoothing modifiers to the model in Blender in hopes that it would be free of imperfections.
3. I tried converting the `dae` file to SceneKit's own `scn` file.
4. I tried configuring the `SCNPhysicsShape`'s `options` parameter in various ways, including the use of `.scale`, `.type`, `.collisionMargin`, and `.keepAsCompound`. Example:

```
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: cube, options: [.scale: cube.scale, .collisionMargin: 0.1])
```

5. I tried changing the `friction` and `restitution` of both the cube and ball. Less friction/restitution did not solve the problem, nor did *more* of it.
6. I tried disabling continuous collision detection by removing the ball's `continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold`.

I'm not sure how the following code will help diagnose this problem, but here it is anyway:

```
//Create the cube's physics body:
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: cube)             
cube.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: shape)

cube.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.floor.rawValue
cube.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicObjects.rawValue
cube.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.nothing.rawValue
cube.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
cube.physicsBody?.allowsResting = false
cube.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5
cube.physicsBody?.friction = 0.75

//Create the ball's physics body:
let ballGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
ballNode?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(
   type: .dynamic,
   shape: SCNPhysicsShape(
        geometry: ballGeo
   )
)
        
ballNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.dynamicObjects.rawValue
ballNode?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.staticObjects.rawValue
ballNode?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.staticObjects.rawValue | CollisionTypes.floor.rawValue
ballNode?.physicsBody?.allowsResting = false
ballNode?.physicsBody?.continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold = 0.9 //Tried it with and without this property.
ballNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5
ballNode?.physicsBody?.charge = 4.0
ballNode?.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2
ballNode?.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 1.0
ballNode?.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.4
ballNode?.physicsBody?.mass = 2.0
```

**Question:** Why might this problem be occurring? Is it a SceneKit problem, as this question presupposes -- or is it a Blender problem about which I will need to post a question on another forum?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:**
Since writing this post, I've been unable to reproduce this problem *when using Blender's default cube*. I'm not sure how I got it wrong on that point, but I digress.

I *have* been able to reproduce the problem when using a slightly more complex shape created in Blender, however. And in doing so, here's what I learned:

If I enable the visualization of physics bodies via `scnView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes`, I can actually *see* the features that are causing the ball to bounce. Visually, they appear as red lines that define the shape of the physics body. So, whenever the ball rolls over these red lines, it bounces.

I tried removing any unnecessary vertices from the model in Blender, but that only helped a tiny bit. Here's a screenshot of the model in Blender that shows the wireframe. As you can see, there isn't much going on outside the holes. The surface outside the holes looks like it should be fine, but in SceneKit, it's a mess of physics body...lines...or whatever they are, spidering out in weird directions.

So, I've learned a lot about what's going on -- and it does seem like it's a SceneKit issue to me -- but I still don't know how to solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a **static** `physicsBody` of type `concavePolyhedron` instead of the `convexHull` for your cube like geometry. Usually this does the trick.

here is some example (with additional scale factor):

```
let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: shape, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron, SCNPhysicsShape.Option.scale: SCNVector3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]))
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/shapetype/1508890-concavepolyhedron

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. And because `concavePolyhedron` follows the geometry more closely than `convexHull`, I would expect it to make the problem worse -- not better -- if the model has some kind of surface flaws. I've basically given up on solving the problem in this way. Instead, I'm achieving a similar effect using multiple `SCNBox` instead of a single mesh from Blender. The ball still bounces undesirably when it rolls over the edge where the `SCNBox`'s meet -- but that's a different problem, I guess.

Comment: This is really strange. I use plently of models I created in Blender in my Games, where also small spheres roll across them, and I never faced such issues. Does your model contain multiple geometry objects put together or is it one single geometry?

Comment: can you share the blender model? or parts of your project?